# Output html format data from database using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have php form where I am retrieving data which is saved in html format and trying to display in html using AJAX call but I am not able to retrieve this html format data getting the error as undefined.The data is saved in database using CKEditor.

//My PHP code

```
 $data1=array();
$query = $db->query("select * from table1 where value1='".$value."' ");

  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

      $data1['value1'] = $row['value1'];
       $data1['value2'] = $row['value2'];

  }
  $data2=array();
  $query = $db->query("select * from table2 where value2='".$value2."'");
  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data2['value2'] = $row['value2'];

     $data2['value3'] = $row['value3'];
     $data2['value4'] = $row['value4'];
     $data2['value5'] = $row['value5'];



  }

  //return json data

  echo json_encode(array('data1' => json_encode($data1), 'data2'=>json_encode($data2), 'UTF-8');
```

}

**here value3,value4,value5 are html format data.**

//My AJAX code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#Form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // stops the form submission

      $.ajax({
         url:$(this).attr('action'), // action attribute of form to send the values
       type:$(this).attr('method'), // method used in the form
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // data to be sent to php
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(data){

       //main
      var data1 = JSON.parse(data['data1']);
      var data2 = JSON.parse(data['data2']);

        $('#value1').val(data1.value1);



              alert(data2.value3);//Getting error as **UNDEFINED** here

         },
         error:function(err){
             alert(err);
         }
       });

    });
    });
```

Here value2,value3 contains MEDIUMTEXT data.Same value2 gets displayed if it is not encoded in json.
Kindly help in solving the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to see what only alert(data2) gives

Comment: For a quick test. Just replace this ```echo json_encode(array('data1' => $data1, 'data2'=>$data2));``` inplace of your code & see once.

Comment: alert(data2) is displaying as false